# Chart.Js - Background Bar in Chart Bar

Tags: chart.js

I use Chart.js to create the horizontal bar of my chart. At this point I have is what is the first image.
But I need to create a "BackgroundBar" with percentage, but I do not know how I can do it. Can someone help me?

This is my output right Now.

[image: Actual]

This is the chart I want..

[image: What I want]

***My code snippet is like below..***

```js
var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart').getContext('2d');

        var purple_orange_gradient = bar_ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 250, 0);
        purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(0.0, 'rgb(237, 28, 36)');
        purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(0.25, 'rgb(228, 81, 173)');
        purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgb(194, 112, 215)');
        purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(0.75, 'rgb(158, 143, 239)');
        purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgb(106, 159, 247)');

        var bar_chart = new Chart(bar_ctx, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19],
                    backgroundColor: purple_orange_gradient,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: purple_orange_gradient,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        categorySpacing: 0,
                        barThickness: 20
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                            //max:100
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<canvas id="bar-chart" width="300" height="125"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a ChartJS plugin called - [**chartjs-plugin-annotation**](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation).

**DEMO**

```js
var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart').getContext('2d');

var purple_orange_gradient = bar_ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 250, 0);
purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(0.0, 'rgb(237, 28, 36)');
purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(0.25, 'rgb(228, 81, 173)');
purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgb(194, 112, 215)');
purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(0.75, 'rgb(158, 143, 239)');
purple_orange_gradient.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgb(106, 159, 247)');

var bar_chart = new Chart(bar_ctx, {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue"],
      datasets: [{
         label: '# of Votes',
         data: [12, 19],
         backgroundColor: purple_orange_gradient,
         hoverBackgroundColor: purple_orange_gradient,
         borderWidth: 0
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            categorySpacing: 0,
            barThickness: 20
         }],
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      },
      annotation: {
         annotations: [{
            type: 'box',
            drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw',
            id: 'bg-bar-1',
            xScaleID: 'x-axis-0',
            xMin: 0,
            xMax: 10,
            backgroundColor: '#7f7f7f',
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/master/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="bar-chart" width="300" height="125"></canvas>
```

To learn more about this plugin and it­*'s* use cases, refer [**here**](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation#chartjs-plugin-annotationjs).